# how to prevent web service from being accessed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

The problem (***which I think is a problem***) that my webservice i.e. AddComplaints.asmx can be opened by typing a link, by anybody.

```
192.168.0.3:89/DM/AddComplaints.asmx
```

I have given this to android developer who wants to consume this service and working ok but my question is that is it ok to leave it like this or is there any way that it can't be opened by general public i.e. by typing a link.

Or is it normal to have it like this ?

Comment: personally I wouldn't use an ip address, this address is only an internal address local to the network your using. But you cant really prevent its access if its a web service, that's the point that it can be accessed by all and sundry.  If you want only authorised users to access it then you would need an api key that is shared between you and the android app, or the app user if you want to go down to a user level.

Comment: @SimonPrice sir the ip i provided is old one for my local system, now it's being deployed on an online real server and it's accessible by everybody so i am worried

Comment: is it normal placing them open like this though I have used parametrized query behind it

Comment: now it is something like 103.xxx.xxx.xx/DM/AddComplaints.asmx

Comment: first, what are the main concerns? second, a webservice is designed to be consumed by anyone, third, yes I would have a method that takes parameters in it such as an api key, and any other variables that you need to consume as part of the service to produce a result.  An API key would be used as your route of authentication.  most web services that I know of all carry an API key of some sort to ensure the right person \ system is accessing and is authorised to do so.

Comment: with the 103.xx ... i still wouldn't use an ip address, if this address changes for whatever reason youll break your app, where a URL, if you change host will stay the same and automatically be redirected to the correct IP

Comment: I dont think anybody outside of your domain can consume this service, becouse of the CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) policy. They can only see the metadata which you can also prevent publishing from web.config

Comment: sir my main concern is the way 'it can be accessed by anybody beside android user'

Comment: 2ndly he  is not the only android user, i will be installed on many android phones

Comment: authenticate against the app or the user with an API key then otherwise anyone will be able to access it

Comment: @SimonPrice so if i don't give him the ip address then how he will ccess it remotely ?

Comment: ok sir, that's a great idea, but 2nd thing is that as u said not to use IP address then how he will access it without IP ADDRESS ?

Comment: `https://yoururl/DM/AddComplaints.asmx`

Comment: @user5820210 - They can access it with a domain name - like `http://www.example.com/DM/AddComplaints.asmx`.

Comment: @SimonPrice we don't have a URL, it is this way yet

Comment: Then you are going to run into a lot of issues further down the line and break the app for everyone when the IP address changes once its in a live environment. It also sounds like you've not thought this through much either.

Comment: @SimonPrice our firm has hired a server, and they haven't provided me the URL and says we haven't yet \

Comment: im stepping away from this as this has gone way off topic and I vote to close the question.

Comment: @SimonPrice I have got my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Often, you can add a HTTP header, e.g. `Authorization`, to the request. You can check this header on the server and return 401, if its value does not correspond to what you expect. You can use a preshared key (e.g. Guid) with you app developer.

It's not perfect, especially when using http instead of https, but it clearly eliminates a lot of issues. You can then extend the token recognition up to your needs, e.g. from constants in your code to a flexible token management with a separate backend for each consumer app and environment (development tokens, production tokens, etc.).

Comment: sir nice to know but i have recently checked many webservices and majority of them are open the way mine is , is it ok ?

Comment: Absolutely yes! Open is always good. However, if I interpret your webservice name correctly, that means, that everybody will be able to commit complaints, also using a small robot program or whatever. If this is something you can live with, then it's ok.

Comment: yes a service consumed by android to register complaints int my database. so that's why I asked